# My First Code - Do I need to add error messages?

Tags: python, revit

This is my first bit of code. I'm trying to make an exe that we can add to our login that will check a .txt file for a date and then copy a directory from a network drive to peoples local.  I'm doing this becuase in Dynamo (a revit addin) packages (similar to python modules) work best when they are kept on the local drive. I want to keep everyone's packages identical so that my scripts work with everyone. I'm sorry if this post is too general for stackoverflow but I'm very new to coding and because of that I have a few questions. The code has worked for me so far but I kind of want some feed back before I add this to 30 people's computers a mess something up.

1. Should I be adding any error capturing to this? I've seen similar things where people used try statements. Would that be helpful here?
2. I've also read someone describe a Inno Setup procedure that would recreate the deleted directory if there was somekind of error so that there would be no change to the local drive. I don't know how to do this in python other than copying the local directory somewhere else and deleting the copy if its not needed.  It seems kind of silly to be because if the copy from the network would fail why would I expect a very similar code to work?
3. This code would rarily actually copy the directory to people's local. I only forsee changing the packages we use every few months after an initial period of more frequent changes. Would there be a better way to do this so this is run less frequently or should I not worry about including this in every login?

I started this by looking at this thread which used Inno Setup but I got too confused trying to understand what was even going on and decided to try python which I atleast took a couple tutorials in.  https://forum.dynamobim.com/t/distribute-dynamo-in-an-organizational-context/28809

```
import shutil
import os

# Local standard Packages
# C:/Users/!!!User Name here!!!/AppData/Roaming/Dynamo/DynamoRevit/2.0/packages

# Local Prorubim Nodes
# May need to add later if we start using Dyno for shortcut keys and dynamo script management
# C:/Program Files/Prorubim Nodes

# !!! Temp Location !!! --Change this to the final location before implementing across company.
# X:/Revit/Dynamo Dev Temp 19-02-22/Test Python 19-02-22/Packages
#   X:/Revit/Dynamo Dev Temp 19-02-22/Test Python 19-02-22/Packages/JDRM Packages Version.txt

# Gets current user name fix paths below.
import getpass
user_name = getpass.getuser()
print(user_name)


# rmtree delete local
# copytree copies the directory on network
def update_package():
    shutil.rmtree("C:/Users/" + user_name + "/AppData/Roaming/Dynamo/Dynamo Revit/2.0/packages")
    shutil.copytree("X:/Revit/Dynamo Dev Temp 19-02-22/Test Python 19-02- 
                22/Packages",
                "C:/Users/" + user_name + "/AppData/Roaming/Dynamo/Dynamo 
                Revit/2.0/packages")

# Checks to see if the version file exists on local drive
version_local_exists = os.path.isfile("C:/Users/" + user_name + 
"/AppData/Roaming/Dynamo/Dynamo Revit/2.0/packages/JDRM Packages 
Version.txt")


# If version file doesn't exist it runs update_package function. If it does exist then it checks first line for date.
if version_local_exists:
    # local version file
    version_local_file = open("C:/Users/" + user_name + 
    "/AppData/Roaming/Dynamo/Dynamo Revit/2.0/packages/JDRM Packages 
    Version.txt", "r")
    version_local_date = version_local_file.read()
    version_local_file.close()

    # network version file
    version_network_file = open("X:/Revit/Dynamo Dev Temp 19-02-22/Test Python 
    19-02-22/Packages/JDRM Packages Version.txt", "r")
    version_network_date = version_network_file.read()
    version_network_file.close()

    # print for easier checking in python
    print(version_local_date)
    print(version_network_date)

    if version_local_date == version_network_date:
        print("Up to date version on local drive.")
    else:
        update_package()
        print("Upgrade has been run.")

else:
    update_package()
    print("First time install.")

print("C:/Users/" + user_name + "/AppData/Roaming/Dynamo/Dynamo Revit/2.0/packages")
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is get rid of the `"C:/Users/" + user_name + 
    "/AppData/` lines in your code, as I can see that resulting in errors quite often.

Instead, what I would suggest is  using `%AllUsersAppData%` (you can look into [Recognized Environment Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-recognized-environment-variables) for more information about that).

This should allow you to get rid of the need to import the username into the code.

Comment: Would I use this? "C:/%AllUsersAppData%/Dynamo/Dynamo Revit/2.0/packages" I tried looking it up and it appears that it will give the roaming folder automatically. I haven't seen examples of it used this way, but perhaps I just don't know what to search for.

Comment: I've seen this before `src="C:\Users\%s\AppData\OpenOffice\work.txt" %(getpass.getuser())`.

Comment: %AllUsersAppData% already contains "C:/".

Let me correct myself though, if you want to easily write to the roaming folder, try this: "%AppData%/Dynamo/Dynamo Revit/2.0/packages".

An easy way to test if the folder path is working is to simply copy and paste the path to your file explorer address bar.

Comment: I'm getting these errors when I try to use %AppData% --return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror) The old method still works.